# Access User Provided Service variables from PCF using .NET core

Tags: java, .net, .net-core, pcf, pcfdev

I have a .NET core webapi running on PCF, Ive Create a user-provided service (cups) that contain my database credentials

```
cf cups my-proj-db -p '{"username":"dba", "password":"dbapass", "server":"whateverserver:1433", "database":"schools"}'
```

when I log onto PCF and go to

> Settings->Environment Variables->View Env Vars

I am able to see the username, db, etc under

```
 "system_env_json": {
    "VCAP_SERVICES": {
      "user-provided": [...
```

Now i want to retrieve the DB values so in my .NET code I do

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("vcap.services.my-proj-db.credentials.server",EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)
```

I also tired `EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine & EnvironmentVariableTarget.User`

but the value is always null, I know in Java this is how they retrieve it, but how do i do it in .NET core?

Just a side note, if i add a costume variable directly to PCF like

```
cf set-env my-app-name ENV_VAR_NAME MyFunkyName
```

I am **able** to get the value by

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ENV_VAR_NAME", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)
```

Appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so finally, was able to get this to work using Steeltoe extension. Here is what all is required.

install the following nuget packages

```
Steeltoe.Common.Hosting
Steeltoe.Extensions.Configuration.CloudFoundryCore
Steeltoe.Extensions.Logging.DynamicSerilogCore
Steeltoe.Management.CloudFoundryCore
```

then Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.ConfigureCloudFoundryOptions(Configuration);
}
```

then in program.cs

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}    

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
       Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .UseCloudHosting() //Enable listening on a Env provided port
           .AddCloudFoundryConfiguration() //Add cloud-foundry environment variables as a configuration source
           .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
           {
               webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
           });
```

then in which ever class you want to access the values you have to do following

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Steeltoe.Extensions.Configuration.CloudFoundry;

 public class EnvironmentManager
    {
        private CloudFoundryApplicationOptions _appOptions { get; set; }
        private CloudFoundryServicesOptions _serviceOptions { get; set; }

        public EnvironmentManager(IOptions<CloudFoundryApplicationOptions> appOptions, IOptions<CloudFoundryServicesOptions> serviceOptions)
        {
            _appOptions = appOptions.Value;
            _serviceOptions = serviceOptions.Value;
        }
```

you can then wherever you want to access the values you could just do

```
var value = _serviceOptions.Services["user-provided"]
                           .First(q => q.Name.Equals("my-proj-db"))
                           .Credentials["username"].Value;
```